# How to get envelope ? How to express constant along a curve?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I am studying the Monge Cone in first order differential equation:
$$F(x,y,z,p,q)$$, whare $z=u(x,y),p=u_x,q=u_y$. And the Monge Cone is the envelope of the tangent planes $$z-z_0=p(x-x_0)+q(p)(y-y_0).$$ To get the Monge Cone, it will base on the following theorem:

If the family of lines is $$y=m(a)x+b(a)=w(x;a)$$, where $a$ is a parameter, then we find the envelope by using: $$\partial_aw(x;a)=0$$ to eliminate a.

In this application, $z=w(x,y;a)$ and need to satisfy $\partial_aw(x,y;a)=0$. The book get two results: $$dz=w_xdx+w_ydy$$ $$0=w_{ax}dx+w_{ay}dy$$. I don't know how to get the second equation. And I think the book explains as follow:"...For a fixed value of a, the two equations $z=w(x,y;a)$ and $\partial_aw(x,y;a)=0$ determine a curve $\gamma_a$...the envelope is just the union of these curves $\gamma_a$...Moreover, along $\gamma_a$, a is constant..."

I think the second result equation is from "a is constant along $\gamma_a$", but I don't know how to get it into a math formula. Maybe it is a multi-calculus problem.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2533810/11127